# New pre hung interior door is 28" and the old area was 29 11/26 is this too big of an area to use this door?

Tags: doors

My old door was 29. 11/16" and the new pre hung interior door is 28". Is this gap too big if an area to use this door. The other threads all have smaller gaps. Also should I butt up to one side or split on each side?  The trim is 2. 1/2" so the gap can be hidden. 
Thanks.

Comment: It appears as if you've asked the same question twice. Please delete one of the questions, or flag it for moderator attention and they'll delete it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you’ve accidentally created a couple of accounts. If you’d like to merge them (there are some [advantages](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to doing so), the instructions are [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a split jamb door with the casing already attached?  If so, then if the casing hides the gap with room left on the outer edge of the casing to fasten, the door will work fine for the rough opening.  The most important part of the installation (other than plumb & level) is that you cut or otherwise use snug-fitting shims frequently -at least, one shim behind every hinge, one shim near the door strike with one or two more above and below the door strike.  You can't overdo it, good shimming is what keeps the door in place through the years.  Important: make sure to put a nail, or better yet a trim screw, through the jamb, through the shim, and solidly into the framing.  After that, nail the casing, fill, caulk and paint, and you're all set.